# Using .batch with list of parameters in pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm running nodejs and pg-promise, and would like to use the batch function for creating a transaction with a BEGIN and COMMIT surrounding the multiple UPDATEs.

This is my code:

```
db.tx(function (t) {
    return this.batch(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            return db.any('UPDATE ... ', [car_id, cars[i].votes]);
        }
    });
})
```

However, it seems not to be working as nothing happens. Isn't it possible to create my batch-list for input like that?

Comment: Examples for this are everywhere, starting from the official documentation: [Transactions](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#transactions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch) does not take a function as parameter, it takes an array of promises to resolve.

And there are plenty of examples of how to use it (on StackOverflow also), starting from the official documentation: [Transactions](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#transactions).

For a set of updates you would simply create an array of update queries and then execute them using [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/spex/global.html#batch):

```
db.tx(t => {
    const queries = cars.map(c => {
        return t.none('UPDATE ... ', [c.car_id, c.votes]);
    });
    return t.batch(queries);
})
    .then(data => {
        // success
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error
    });
```

**Extra**

Multiple updates of the same type can be executed as a single query, for a much better performance. See [Performance Boost](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Performance-Boost) and method [helpers.update](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.update).

Comment: Sorry, but struggled with the correct method. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen I have added further studies on the subject about multiple updates, in case you get there some day ;)